Trying to make a helper function to replace special characters in a string
So as the question states, i'm trying to build a small helper function that will catch and fix special characters, I wasn't sure where to go with it so opted for an object containing the characters, a check to see if it's included and if so replace the character in the string with the appropriate object entry.
Im now however getting stuck, i've got the object and the check to see if it is in fact included. I just don't know how to target the piece of the string, and then replace it. I tried using includes and replace but it doesn't seem to work.
Here's my code:
export function fixEncoding(str) {
  const specialChars = {
    "&Agrave;": "À ",
    "&Aacute;": "Á",
    "&Acirc;": "Â",
    "&Atilde;": "Ã",
    "&Auml;": "Ä",
    "&Aring;": "Å",
    "&agrave;": "à",
    "&aacute;": "á",
    "&acirc;": "â",
    "&atilde;": "ã",
    "&auml;": "ä",
    "&aring;": "å",
    "&AElig;": "Æ",
    "&aelig;": "æ",
    "&szlig;": "ß",
    "&Ccedil;": "Ç",
    "&ccedil;": "ç",
    "&Egrave;": "È",
    "&Eacute;": "É",
    "&Ecirc;": "Ê",
    "&Euml;": "Ë",
    "&egrave;": "è",
    "&eacute;": "é",
    "&ecirc;": "ê",
    "&euml;": "ë",
    "&#131;": "ƒ",
    "&Igrave;": "Ì",
    "&Iacute;": "Í",
    "&Icirc;": "Î",
    "&Iuml;": "Ï",
    "&igrave;": "ì",
    "&iacute;": "í",
    "&icirc;": "î",
    "&iuml;": "ï",
    "&Ntilde;": "Ñ",
    "&ntilde;": "ñ",
    "&Ograve;": "Ò",
    "&Oacute;": "Ó",
    "&Ocirc;": "Ô",
    "&Otilde;": "Õ",
    "&Ouml;": "Ö",
    "&ograve;": "ò",
    "&oacute;": "ó",
    "&ocirc;": "ô",
    "&otilde;": "õ",
    "&ouml;": "ö",
    "&Oslash;": "Ø",
    "&oslash;": "ø",
    "&#140;": "Œ",
    "&#156;": "œ",
    "&#138;": "Š",
    "&#154;": "š",
    "&Ugrave;": "Ù",
    "&Uacute;": "Ú",
    "&Ucirc;": "Û",
    "&Uuml;": "Ü",
    "&ugrave;": "ù",
    "&uacute;": "ú",
    "&ucirc;": "û",
    "&uuml;": "ü",
    "&#181;": "µ",
    "&#215;": "×",
    "&Yacute;": "Ý",
    "&#159;": "Ÿ",
    "&yacute;": "ý",
    "&yuml;": "ÿ",
    "&#176;": "°",
    "&#134;": "†",
    "&#135;": "‡",
    "&lt;": "<",
    "&gt;": ">",
    "&#177;": "±",
    "&#171;": "«",
    "&#187;": "»",
    "&#191;": "¿",
    "&#161;": "¡",
    "&#183;": "·",
    "&#149;": "•",
    "&#153;": "™",
    "&copy;": "©",
    "&reg;": "®",
    "&#167;": "§",
    "&#182;": "¶",
    "&#039;": "'",
    "&quot;": '"',
  };

  let isinclude = (str, obj) => (
    (str = str.replace("/", "")),
    Object.keys(obj).reduce((a, v) => a || str.includes(v), false)
  );

  console.log(isinclude(str, specialChars));

  for (let i = 0; i < specialChars.length; i++) {
    if (str.includes(specialChars[str])) {
      console.log(str);
      const newStr = str.replace(`${i}`, specialChars[str]);
      return newStr;
    } else return str;
  }

  // return str.replace(/&#039;+/g, "'").replace(/&quot;+/g, '"');
}



Does this answer your question? Convert HTML Character Entities back to regular text using javascript

The whole for block looks like a mangled mess. specialChars.length doesn't exist, most likely neither does specialChars[str], replacing \${i}`` makes no sense, and the loop returns in every branch.

@DouwedeHaan im not sure it will as im looking to create a regular function I can use on a string, that's being mapped into an object, i'll have to look into this but in the immediate im not sure

@ASDFGerte would you be able to point out how id fix it?

Those "special characters" are HTML entities. There are ready-made processes for encoding and decoding HTML entities; you do not need to reinvent this with a long list of sequences you have accumulated yourself, and which don't even cover all possible HTML entities in existence.

First, specialChars is an object, not an array, so you use specialChars.length, Also, your replacement logic inside the loop isn't correctly set up to handle the replacement for all occurrences of each character.


function fixEncoding(str) {
  const specialChars = {
    "&Agrave;": "À ",
    "&Aacute;": "Á",
    "&Acirc;": "Â",
    "&Atilde;": "Ã",
    "&Auml;": "Ä",
    "&Aring;": "Å",
    "&agrave;": "à",
    "&aacute;": "á",
    "&acirc;": "â",
    "&atilde;": "ã",
    "&auml;": "ä",
    "&aring;": "å",
    "&AElig;": "Æ",
    "&aelig;": "æ",
    "&szlig;": "ß",
    "&Ccedil;": "Ç",
    "&ccedil;": "ç",
    "&Egrave;": "È",
    "&Eacute;": "É",
    "&Ecirc;": "Ê",
    "&Euml;": "Ë",
    "&egrave;": "è",
    "&eacute;": "é",
    "&ecirc;": "ê",
    "&euml;": "ë",
    "&#131;": "ƒ",
    "&Igrave;": "Ì",
    "&Iacute;": "Í",
    "&Icirc;": "Î",
    "&Iuml;": "Ï",
    "&igrave;": "ì",
    "&iacute;": "í",
    "&icirc;": "î",
    "&iuml;": "ï",
    "&Ntilde;": "Ñ",
    "&ntilde;": "ñ",
    "&Ograve;": "Ò",
    "&Oacute;": "Ó",
    "&Ocirc;": "Ô",
    "&Otilde;": "Õ",
    "&Ouml;": "Ö",
    "&ograve;": "ò",
    "&oacute;": "ó",
    "&ocirc;": "ô",
    "&otilde;": "õ",
    "&ouml;": "ö",
    "&Oslash;": "Ø",
    "&oslash;": "ø",
    "&#140;": "Œ",
    "&#156;": "œ",
    "&#138;": "Š",
    "&#154;": "š",
    "&Ugrave;": "Ù",
    "&Uacute;": "Ú",
    "&Ucirc;": "Û",
    "&Uuml;": "Ü",
    "&ugrave;": "ù",
    "&uacute;": "ú",
    "&ucirc;": "û",
    "&uuml;": "ü",
    "&#181;": "µ",
    "&#215;": "×",
    "&Yacute;": "Ý",
    "&#159;": "Ÿ",
    "&yacute;": "ý",
    "&yuml;": "ÿ",
    "&#176;": "°",
    "&#134;": "†",
    "&#135;": "‡",
    "&lt;": "<",
    "&gt;": ">",
    "&#177;": "±",
    "&#171;": "«",
    "&#187;": "»",
    "&#191;": "¿",
    "&#161;": "¡",
    "&#183;": "·",
    "&#149;": "•",
    "&#153;": "™",
    "&copy;": "©",
    "&reg;": "®",
    "&#167;": "§",
    "&#182;": "¶",
    "&#039;": "'",
    "&quot;": '"',
  };

  Object.keys(specialChars).forEach(key => {
    str = str.replace(new RegExp(key, 'g'), specialChars[key]);
  });

  return str;
}

const htmlEncodedString = "This is an encoded string with &quot;quotes&quot; and an apostrophe (&#039;).";
const decodedString1 = fixEncoding(htmlEncodedString);
console.log(decodedString1);




Ah i see where i was going wrong, I was looping over it as if it was an array and also only targeting the first occurrence. Thanks for the insight.

You don't need an object for something as simple as character replacement.
const  Bad=['À','Á','Â','Ã','Ä','Å']; // add all your undesirable chars here

const Good=['A','A','A','A','A','A']; // add all their replacements here


for (let i=0; i<Bad.length; i++) {

 str=str.replaceAll(Bad[i],Good[i]);

}


If it's HTML Entities you need to replace you can do so in just one swoop...
var str='&Agrave &Aacute; &Acirc; &Atilde; &Auml; &Aring; &agrave; &aacute; &acirc; &atilde; &auml; &aring;';


str=decodeURIComponent(str);


document.write(str);

Output: À Á Â Ã Ä Å à á â ã ä å

Err… HTML entities != URI components. The "decoding" is in fact done by document.write here (because HTML in a document is interpreted by the browser)…
